# How can i force that tinyMCE does not convert <b> tags to <strong> tags?

Tags: javascript, editor, tinymce

when i use the html editor tinyMCE and i paste code inside, it converts the html `<b>` tags into `<strong>` tags.

Does andybody knows how can i force this editor to prevent such convertions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, use this piece of code in your tinymce init

```
    // Override internal formats  
    formats: {
        bold : {inline : 'b' },  
        //italic : {inline : 'i' },
        //underline : {inline : 'u'}
    },
```

Comment: that is correct, but in some CMSs b-tags need to stay in use for compatibility reasons

Comment: and many people us something like <b class='someClass'>....</b> but when changed to <strong class...> it does not work

Comment: and is there a way to implement that newlines are not like <br> or <p> that inserts something like 2 new lines? I mean like natural editing as with word o any other wordprocessor.

Comment: actually i do not know of such functionality, but you may implement it using an own plugin. this would not be that difficult to realize.

Comment: How can i do this with an own plugin? Sorry but my knowlegdes of tiny are very small... thanks

Comment: here is a general tutorial: http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Creating_a_plugin . for your case you would need to listen on the return key and modify the editors content as you please + maybe stopPropagation to cancel the default behaviour. But to explain this in depth you should create another question (this does not belong here).

Comment: thanks for that tutorial... but the code with the format does still not work... y put this tinyMCE.init({
       formats: {
                bold : {inline : 'b' }  
              },
      mode : "textareas",
      theme : "advanced",
      plugins : "wordcount",
      width   : "100%"}....  the code shows again the <strong> instead of the <b>

Comment: which tinymce version are you using?

Comment: of course you should have the b-tag in your valid_elements parameter

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli In HTML5 `strong` is [no longer](http://html5doctor.com/i-b-em-strong-element/) a substitute for `b` . Technically TinyMCE should now have all four elements `strong`,`em`,`b` and `i`. Converting a <b> to <strong> is now pretty bad for newly written content with HTML5 semantic in mind.

Comment: @hexalys true. Auto substituting is a bad idea in general. As for `<i>` and `<b>` they still should only be used when there are no other more suitable elements.

Answer (score 4):

You might try going to your plugin manager, finding the plugin "Editor - TinyMCE," and under Basic Options look for the "Extended Valid Elements" field and add your HTML5 tags in there. like in your case: `<strong>` and `<br>`
Then it will not ignore your `<strong>` and `<br>`.

Thanks Hope you will like it ! :)

Comment: awesome, thanks for this tip, took me a while to get this running

Answer (score 1):

Here is what works for me 
tinyMCE.init({
    valid_elements : "a[href|target=_blank],b,div[align],br"
.......

Here you can set all elements that are ok for the tiny even if they are deprecated such as b (replaced to strong, or i replaced to em). With this tag tiny won't replace that what match inside valid_elements.

Tiny itself has a few rules when the editor is create : 
valid_elements : "@[id|class|style|title|dir

where we can see wich changes it makes in order to match it's criteria. 
In my case some html's had a 'b' tag with a class inside that i don't must touch 'b class='aClass'', so the valid_elements for such thing is 
valid_elements : "b[class|id],i" where we set valid tags inside the b such as class or id,. If we don't set any options inside [..] the 'b class='aClass'' will be replace with a simple 'b'.

Hope this helps to someone.

The link with some more explanation
http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration:valid_elements

Comment: but you still need the format setting in order to make tinymce use b-tags instead of strongs!

Comment: I needed this along with the accepted answer to get my <b> tags back.