# Tags being converted when Full HTML is used as Input format

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6, tinymce

I do find a strange behaviour when i add a content to the body of a block and use the `input format` as full html my `<b>` tags are being converted to `<strong>` tags.I really can't get my styling correctly.I am using `TinyMCE 3.5.8` module for full html.Could someone help me what might be causing this action..??

Input:

```
<div class='content>'
<b>Lorem Ipsum</b>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum         has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
</div>
```

Output:

```
<div class='content>'
    <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum         has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an issue with the way TinyMCE is handling the HTML tags. It automatically replaces several tags with their newer versions (like `b` being replaced with `strong` in your case).

Do take note that this is not a bad behavior per se, as the end result is the same, however it can be confusing. In HTML5, the newer `strong` tag is preferred over the older `b` tag. [Here's a page that explains why](http://html5doctor.com/i-b-em-strong-element/).

[Here's a relevant SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094697/how-can-i-force-that-tinymce-does-not-convert-b-tags-to-strong-tags) which answers how to changes this behavior for the TinyMCE script itself. I am not sure how you're including TinyMCE in drupal. If you're using the [WYSIWYG module](https://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg), then you can override the TinyMCE settings using the [hook_wysiwyg_editor_settings_alter](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!wysiwyg!wysiwyg.api.php/function/hook_wysiwyg_editor_settings_alter/7) hook.